# Склонение названия с твёрдым знаком на конце

Tags: склонение, кавычки, названия, существительные

Объясните, пожалуйста, на примере белорусской группы "Садъ", как правильно склонять это слово? Встретился вариант **"Садъ"-у**. Кажется, он наиболее логичный.
Про возможность обходить эту ситуацию при помощи прибавления родового слова "группа" писать не надо. Это и так очевидно.

Comment: Екатерина, lex_ander, Римма Михайлова, behemothus, благодарю за информативные ответы. Всем по плюсу. Выбрать какой-то один, честно, затрудняюсь.

Answer (score 2):

Твёрдый знак (Ъ) на конце слов и частей сложных слов был исключен в 1918 году — во время реформы русской орфографии.
Думаю, что особенное название ["Садъ"](https://www.last.fm/ru/music/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8A/+wiki) ("СадЪ") — это стилизованная дань дореволюционному времени. Есть у группы и альбом с особенным названием — "ЗооСадЪ".
А склонять всё надо по современным правилам: в "Саде", "Садом", в "ЗооСаде".

Вспомнились и другие названия: "Провалъ" — в "Провале"; ["Подвалъ бродячей собаки"](http://www.vsobaka.ru/) — в "Подвале бродячей собаки"; "Пивной Банкъ" — в "Пивном Банке".

Answer (score 1):

Видела название группы вот в таком оформлении - **"СадЪ"**.

Буква Ъ в названии используется как прописная, поэтому можно, наверное, использовать вариант написания падежных форм: *"СадЪу", "СадЪа"*. Это не совсем грамотно, конечно, но  в любом случае за кавычки выносить окончание, да ещё с дефисом,  не стоит.

В Википедии есть статья, посвящённая группе. В ней такое предложение:

***В компании «Мистерия звука» началось переиздание всей дискографии «Садъ'а».***  - Тоже вариант.

Но лучше всего использовать рядом с приложением "СадЪ" определяемое слово *группа*, и тогда менять название группы не придётся:

***10 основных фактов о группе "СадЪ".***

Если "СадЪ" используется как подлежащее, тогда и определяемое слово можно не использовать:

***Вскоре «Садъ» записал свой новый альбом «С котомъ по эту сторону окна».*** (Википедия)

Answer (score 1):

В предположении, что это белорусский *русский* язык: на мой взгляд, сохранять декоративный твердый знак при склонении было бы излишней сентиментальностью со стороны носителей названия или их поклонников и подчёркиванием неполной языковой функциональности выбранного слова. Нет такой необходимости. К примеру, есть у нас печатное издание "**Коммерсантъ**", и даже на его сайте преспокойно располагается кнопка **О "Коммерсанте"**. Единственной особенностью склонения слова "Садъ" должен бы стать предложный падеж. Факультативно (для пущей игривости, заложенной изначально) можно капитализировать последнюю букву: **в "СадЕ**" (но не *в "СадУ"* - в нём не гуляют).

Answer (score 1):

Да так и склонять, как склоняли бы без этого ера (твердого знака по современному). 
Пример - газета "КоммерсантЪ". Они вовсю этот ер пользуют, даже фирменным знаком сделали (*Как писал "Ъ"*), но в косвенных падежах не используют. Да так и не было никогда, чтобы он сохранялся перед гласными. 
Ну уж если очень хотите поприкалываться, можете с ятем писать в предложном падеже (о "Садѣ")

Две ремарки по поводу комментариев.
1. Я не понимаю, что такое "белорусский русский". В белорусском ера вообще никогда не было.
2. Заглавный Ъ на конце слова скорее всего просто отсылка к графике петровских времен - ер тогда возвышался над строкой.